# Having issue in viewing rdlc 2008 in visual studio 2010 and 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created a rdl report in sql server 2008 R2, then i saved it as rdlc.
I created a website in visual studio 2010 and added this rdlc report in it. When i tried to open that report i got below prompt:

> Do you want to convert this report to RDLC 2008 format?  Please click OK to proceed or Cancel to open it in the XML editor.

I clicked on Okay and i got below error meesgae:

> The report definition has an invalid target namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition which cannot be upgraded.

After referring to some forum, i changed my rdlc report top line:

previous code:

> Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" 
>   xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" 
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"

After changes:

> Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" 
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition"

After above changes when i tried to open the report in visual studeio 2010 again i got below error message:

> Deserialization failed: The element 'DataSet' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' has invalid child element 'SharedDataSet' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'. List of possible elements expected: 'Fields, Query, CaseSensitivity, Collation, AccentSensitivity, KanatypeSensitivity, WidthSensitivity, Filters, InterpretSubtotalsAsDetails' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' as well as any element in namespace '##other'. Line 7, position 8.

Comment: I have checked the version of report viewer dll in my visual studio, they are pointing to version 10

Comment: Moving from 2008 to 2010 has problems; is this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759798/visual-studio-2008-report-server-project-design-view-not-working/5512850#5512850) related?

Comment: no, i thought the issues is because the report is created using sql server 2008 R2 . So i created another report using sql server 2008 and tried to open it but still not working.